# How to configure test environment using kafka connect and XML config file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am new to kafka, i wrote a piece of code that writes to a topic (A producer).

Now, i was given the task of watching if the content is being written on the topic.

The only information provided from my tech lead was that i should install kafka connect, and use this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<connections>
<connection bootstrap_servers="xxxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096,xxxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096,xxxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096" broker_security_type="SASL_SSL" chroot="/" group="Clusters" groupId="1" host="xxxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com" jaas_config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=&quot;USER&quot; password=&quot;PASSWD&quot;;" keystore_location="" keystore_password="" keystore_privatekey="" name="Worten" port="9096" sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-512" schema_registry_endpoint="" truststore_location="" truststore_password="" version="VERSION_2_7_0"/>
<groups>
<group id="1" name="Clusters"/>
</groups>
</connections>
```

I have absolutely no idea on where or how to import this xml config file. I Installed kafka, put it to run locally but all config files are typically on this format:

`$ cat config/connect-standalone.properties`

partial output:

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096,xxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096,xxxxxxxxx.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9096

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

I tried adding the fields here, but many are missing, any tips would be greatly welcome, i did research for a bit, but i can't find much that helped me.

Thank you!!!

I tried searching for anything that would allow me to start a local standalone consumer cluster so i could see the topics i'm writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect doesn't use XML files. It uses a Java `.properties` file only.

Your properties file shown is missing `SASL_SSL` values that are mentioned in the XML you were given.

The [Kafka quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) covers running Kafka Connect standalone mode, and you can refer the documentation for configuration properties, such as `consumer.` or `producer.` properties that will need configured with SASL/SSL values, such as `consumer.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512`